# Count TCP losses for incoming connection?

Tags: tcp, loss

I control machine A, and am receiving data over TCP from machine B (which I don't control). I want to count / estimate the number of packets this connection loses. What might be the best approach?

- netstat does not seem to give anything very useful; besides I would have trouble sorting out the data for this connection of interest from other network activity.
- I could possibly capture a tcpdump, filter for this connection, and examine all the TCP sequence numbers to see which ones I don't receive in-order. But then, out-of-order delivery isn't the same as "loss". Perhaps I could distinguish these by checking on the timestamps -- if out-of-order packet arrives separated from its expected position by more than 1 RTT, then treat it as a loss?

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't count things you don't have. Any scheme you use will be guesswork.

Comment: Yes, which is why I included 'estimate' as an option. Any ideas as to what the best way of estimating would be?